# Importing the Angular 2 testing classes ComponentFixture & TestBed causing 404 error

Tags: angular, systemjs, angular2-testing

I get this error only when I try to run my jasmine tests. I run them with a spec runner html file.

> zone.js:1382 GET
>   http://localhost:3002/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js/testing
>   404 (Not Found)
>
> zone.js:232 Error: (SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found)

If I just run my app, it works fine.

My spec file that I'm trying to run imports angular 2 testing modules:

`import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';` and that's what is causing the error.

However that line is exactly what is in the [angular 2 testing documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#setup)

My `systemjs.config.js` is also exactly the same as the one in the
[angular 2 documentation](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/testing.html#!#setup).

The issue is that the angular testing module is in `@angular/core` so this line of `systemjs.config.js` should take care of that:

```
map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'js/app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
```

However this is the file structure of `@angular` inside `node_modules` and I have also clicked on "index.js" to show you that that is the file exporting the classes that I want to use in the spec test:

[image]

But the browser shows that it's looking for this during the import:

> zone.js:1382 GET
>   http://localhost:3002/node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js/testing
>   404 (Not Found)

Obviously there can't be a file or folder inside core.umd.js file, so it's easy to see that that is wrong.

I think I probably want it to be looking for this:

> http://localhost:3002/node_modules/@angular/core/testing/index.js

So how do I make it do that? In `systemjs.config.js` surely, I will be doing something to this line?

```
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'js/app',
  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
```

Or adding another mapping after it specifically for the testing modules which are inside `@angular/core`?

I've tried this:

```
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'js/app',
  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/core/testing': 'npm:@angular/core/testing/index.js',
```

and I have also tried this (look at the bottom package):

```
packages: {
  app: {
    main: 'main.js',
    defaultExtension: 'js'
  },
  "node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal": {
    defaultExtension: 'js' 
  },
  'node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core': { 
    defaultExtension: 'js', 
    main: 'index.js'
  },
  '@angular/core/testing': {
    main:'npm:@angular/core/testing/index.js'
  },
```

But both didn't work/cause other issues.

What do I do to fix this error?

My `systemjs.config.js` file:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'js/app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      '@angular/upgrade': 'npm:@angular/upgrade/bundles/upgrade.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js',
    'angular2-google-maps': 'npm:angular2-google-maps',
    'angular2-google-map-auto-complete' : 'npm:angular2-google-map-auto-complete', 
    'ng2-bs3-modal': 'npm:ng2-bs3-modal',
    "ng2-popover": "npm:ng2-popover",
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: 'main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      "node_modules/ng2-bs3-modal": {
        defaultExtension: 'js' 
      },
      'node_modules/angular2-google-maps/core': { 
        defaultExtension: 'js', 
        main: 'index.js'
      },
      '@angular/core/testing': {
        main:'npm:@angular/core/testing/index.js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

my jasmine spec runner html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
  <title>Vepo Unit Tests</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.css">
  <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/jasmine-html.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/jasmine-core/lib/jasmine-core/boot.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- #1. add the system.js and angular libraries -->
  <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
  <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
  <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
  <script>
    Promise.all([
      System.import('js/app/landing-page/landing-page.component.spec.js'),
      System.import('js/app/pipes/my-uppercase.pipe.spec.js'),
      System.import('js/app/landing-page/subcomponents/middle-row.component.spec.js')
    ]).then(window.onload)
      .catch(console.error.bind(console));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

my spec file:

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';

import { MiddleRowComponent } from './middle-row.component';

let comp: MiddleRowComponent;
let fixture: ComponentFixture<MiddleRowComponent>;
let de: DebugElement;
let el: HTMLElement;

describe('MiddleRowComponent', () => {
   beforeEach(() => {
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
         declarations: [MiddleRowComponent], // declare the test component
      });

      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MiddleRowComponent);

      comp = fixture.componentInstance; // MiddleRowComponent test instance

      // query for the title <h1> by CSS element selector
      de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('h1'));
      el = de.nativeElement;
   });

   it('should display original title', () => {
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(el.textContent).toContain(comp.word);
   });

   it('should display a different test title', () => {
      comp.word = 'Test Title';
      fixture.detectChanges();
      expect(el.textContent).toContain('Test Title');
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`@angular/core/testing/package.json` has this code inside:

`{"main": "../bundles/core-testing.umd.js"}`

So I added this to systemjs.config.js mappings:

`'@angular/core/testing': "npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js"`

eg:

```
map: {
  // our app is within the app folder
  app: 'js/app',
  // angular bundles
  '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
  '@angular/core/testing': "npm:@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js",
```

And it works.